# Changing PIVOT function to add a corresponding value instead of SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

From this query:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sqlquery VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT distinct  ',' + QuoteName(idIndice)
                        FROM tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Indexacao as a FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 1, '')      

SET @sqlquery = 'SELECT * FROM
      (      
        select distinct a.id, b.idIndice  
        from tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Documentos as a  
        join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Indexacao as b on a.id = b.idDocumento 
        join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType as c on a.idDocType = c.id
        join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType_Index as d on c.id = d.docTypeId 
        where d.docTypeId = 40      
        and (b.idIndice = 11 AND b.valor = ''11111111'' OR b.idIndice = 12 AND b.valor = ''11111'')       
       ) base
       PIVOT 
       (
        Sum(idIndice) 
        FOR [idIndice] IN (' + @cols + ')
        ) AS finalpivot' 

EXECUTE ( @sqlquery )
```

I get this result:

```
id  10      11     12   13      9
13  NULL    11     12   NULL    NULL
14  NULL    11     12   NULL    NULL
16  NULL    NULL   12   NULL    NULL
```

Instead of using Sum(idIndice) in pivot I would like to find a way to insert the values corresponding to it idIndex.

Those values are stored in the sabe table at a.value
Is this a easy way to perform that? Can´t find this nowhere

Answer (score 0):

If there is a single a.value for each idIndice, then you can simply use MIN(a.value) or MAX(a.value) instead of SUM(idIndice)